# How can I plot these coordinates on a map not knowing their format

Tags: coordinates, google-earth

Trying to plot these coordinates on a map, or convert them to Lat/Long, hoping someone can help me, way over my head. Should be somewhere in the Hess mountains Yukon Territory
y proj 890526.20462877 x proj 507373.11003899.

Comment: Probably some kind of projected coordinate system, but perhaps you have something else for the points (like a UTM zone or similar)?

Comment: http://projfinder.com/

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be `EPSG:3578 NAD83 / Yukon Albers`. It would need a reference point near a village or street crossing to verify that.

You can use the free QGIS software to display your point on a Google or bing background using the Openlayers plugin, and reproject it to WGS84 coordinates.